# how to install additional python packages with pythonbrew

Tags: python, pythonbrew

I am using pythonbrew to install 2.7.2  on my CentOS. 
It has worked before but this time on a separate clean system I am running into an issue.

After installing pythonbrew (which I had to --force since it complained in make test about distutils) I switched to 2.7.2
When I run easy_install setuptools it tries to go system python (2.5). Since I am non superuser this ofcourse failed.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I just ditched pythonbrew and did a multi install of python.
Thereafter I used bash and profile to switch between my python environments.